# Shuffle an Array coding challenge. trouble understanding one part

Tags: javascript

Question:
Shuffle a set of numbers without duplicates.

```
Example:

// Init an array with set 1, 2, and 3.
int[] nums = {1,2,3};
Solution solution = new Solution(nums);

// Shuffle the array [1,2,3] and return its result. Any permutation of [1,2,3] must equally likely to be returned.
solution.shuffle();

// Resets the array back to its original configuration [1,2,3].
solution.reset();

// Returns the random shuffling of array [1,2,3].
solution.shuffle();
```

Answer:

```
 var Solution = function(nums) {

// hold nums in Solution

   this.nums = nums;
};

Solution.prototype.reset = function() {
   return this.nums;
};

Solution.prototype.shuffle = function() {

// create a copy of this.nums, shuffle it, and return it0

const shuffled = this.nums.slice();
const n = shuffled.length;
const swap = (arr, i, j) => {
    let tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}

// swap elements with random elements
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    swap(shuffled, i, Math.floor(Math.random() * n));

return shuffled;
};
```

My question:
The Math.floor(Math.random() * n ) you are getting a random index out of the length of the array. I do not understand, can't this code make duplicates? Say if the length is 3. Cant the formula get the index of 2 and another index of 2, thus making duplicate indexes. Can anyone clarify something I am misunderstanding. Thanks. Does Math.random automatically withdraw indexes that have been used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `Math.floor(Math.random() * n)` expression can evaluate to the same number multiple times, but that's OK, because the random number is being used in `swap`, which switches the number at index `i` with the number at the chosen random index.

If the random index was taken from the original array and added to the array to be returned, eg

```
const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
arrToBeReturned.push(arr[randIndex]);
```

you'd be right, but that's not what the algorithm is doing. Imagine randomly sorting an array of `[1, 2, 3]`:

First iteration of loop: `i` is 0, random index chosen is 2. Swap indicies 0 and 2:

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

Second iteration: `i` is 1, random index chosen is 2. Swap indicies 1 and 2:

```
[3, 1, 2]
```

Third iteration: `i` is 2, random index chosen is 2. Swap indicies 2 and 2:

```
[3, 1, 2]
```

With this code, every index is randomly swapped with another index *at least one time*, ensuring that by the end, the array is randomized without bias (assuming `Math.random` is trustworthy).

Answer (score 1):

**Math.floor(Math.random() * n)** Yes it can eve-valuate to same index but here you're using the number to swap element so this is ok.

> Does Math.random automatically withdraw indexes that have been used?

No it doesn't you need to keep track of previously generated values

What you can do it is have a variable a `object` or `Map` to keep track of previously add index if the random generated index is not already included in that variable than add it to final output else again generate a new index,

But in this case it is not needed.